# if i change a bundle identifier will I still be able to test external developer's app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

I have hired a developer to develop an app for me. I am not a programmer. 
I have on his advice downloaded Xcode so I can import and view the project, by using my personal Apple ID which I have selected from drop down list under Team
He has called the project 'PitchPerfect'
I have also connected my iphone to the computer and selected it from the drop down list.
I have since had the following errors:

*Error 1
'Failed to create provisioning profile'The app ID 'com.xxxxxxxx.PitchPerfect cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again*

*Error 2
No profiles for
'com.xxxxxxxx.PitchPerfect' were found Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.xxxxxxxx.PitchPerfect'.*

***My question is:
If I change the bundle identifier to something else, will I still be able to view and test this app on my computer or will it mess with the configurations?***

Other information:
I have from other forums attempted to select Xcode, Preferences, Accounts and from my AppleID clicked on View Details and there is no button to create next to iOS Development.

Under Signing: Automatically manage signing is checked
Under Provisioning Profile says Xcode managed Profile
Under Signing Certificate says iOS Developer

If you can please assist as I've been trying to sort out this issue for over a week now.

Many thanks in advance
xcodenewbie

Comment: You can safely change the bundleID, just when you run it or the dev runs it, they will have to change it to their bundleID they registered with there apple account, otherwise you should add his account as a team member to your account, then you can use the same bundleID, and you will have more control over the situation. - edit: sorry i think you need an enterprise account to be able to do the team stuff, not sure what type of account you have, [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html)

Comment: I don't want to edit it, I just want to run it on my phone to test it. Do I need a developer account for that or is my usual Apple ID sufficient?

Comment: If you want to build from Xcode and run on device you will need a developer account. You will still need to change the bundleID because the current one is registered to your devs account, so you cant use it unless you are apart of the same team. You can make a free developer account for now, but you will need a paid one to upload to the app store eventually. Alternatively, get your dev to upload builds to TestFlight or HockeyApp, then you wont have to do anything with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the bundle identifier to whatever *you* would normally use.

The reason why you are getting the error is because `com.xxxxxxxx.PitchPerfect` is already registered to them, and in use. You need to select your own (eg. `com.xxxxxxx.YourName`).